# Can i upgrade to PHP 7 and MySQL 5.7 - TYPO3 4.5 CMS

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, upgrade

I want to use `wordpress` on my webspace, and need to upgrade to `PHP 7` and `MySQL 5.7` for this.

But I still have another website on my server created with  `TYPO3 4.5` CMS (which is using `PHP 5.2.x-5.3.x` and `MySQL 5.0.x-5.1.x`).

So I am not sure, if an upgrade in `PHP` and `MySQL` will damage my `typo3` website or if still everything will work?

Hope to hear from you soon, thanks a lot!

Comment: it's this website: http://www.biografische-geschichten.de/en/live-stories/index.html

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools.* Your question may be better suited for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or the [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

1. TYPO3 4.5 will not work with PHP7
2. TYPO3 4.5 is out of support (even ELTS support has ended long ago). Therefore revealing your domain is a great security risk
3. update your TYPO3 installation, at least up to 7.6 LTS (which is currently the lowest supported version and also capable running with PHP 7) (upgrade path is 4.5 -> 6.2 -> 7.6)